# Can mule load balance the servers within cluster?

Tags: mule, cluster-computing, mule-cluster

I have a polling endpoint which reads from database located in North America(NA).I want to cluster my mule servers located in NA,Europe and APAC so that only one instance will be reading from the datasources.
I have couple of questions related to this use case.

1. Whether mule will be able to load balance the instances such that instance in NA will start the polling since datasource is in NA and avoid the latency other instances will have.
2. If the application has multiple non related flows eg Flow 1 polls from datasource1 ,flow 2 polls from datasource 2,can mule cluster run flow 1 in one instance and flow 2 in another intance so that one machine will not be hot red and bear the whole load ?

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

my answers include commercial services but might nevertheless be helpful for your case. It sounds like you have a case that could justify an investment.

1. Check out deploying your app to [CloudHub](http://www.mulesoft.com/platform/saas/cloudhub-ipaas-cloud-based-integration)
2. You want to have a look at the [Batch Processor](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Batch+Processing)

Additionally here is a nice [blog](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/when-etl-met-the-esb-introducing-the-batch-module/) about batch.

I hope that helps.